# import .so file in xamarin studio

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-library

I need to add .so file in xamarin studio android project. I found out some answers about this and did so:

1. add lib folder  add
2. sub-folder armeabi
3. add .so file inside this folder, set properties > always copy, build action: AndroidNativeLibrary

Now I need to declare class instance from this library. for example :

```
Barcode1D test=Barcode1D.getInstanse;
```

but it isn'y visible in the solution .

Answer (score 1):

An `so` is a `C` library, and needs to be called via `P/Invoke`.

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/using_native_libraries/

See **Accessing C Methods from C#** in this [document](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/native_interop/)